# Fitting circle into an angle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, anyone could help me perhaps with this?

Given an angle of an arbitrary degrees, and a circle with radius r. And imagine I would try to push the circle into the angle, touching the two lines of the angle.

What would be the position of the center point of the circle.

[image]

Comment: A start: The vertex of the angle, the center of the circle, and a point of tangency of the circle with a side of the angle form a right triangle. Also, the line through the vertex of the angle and the center of the circle bisects the angle.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the point of tangency $A$, note that $r=OA\cdot\tan\alpha/2$ where $O$ is the origin (vertex of the angle).

Answer (score 0):

This is the derivation:

Given $r = \frac {\sin\frac\theta2}{1+\sin\frac\theta2}R$ where $R$ is the distance from vertex to furthest point on circle (this equation is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444910/finding-the-area-general-case-with-angle-theta/445248#445248).):

$$\text{Distance} = R-r$$

$$\text{Distance} = \frac {1+\sin\frac\theta2}{\sin\frac\theta2}r-r$$